# ModelForms on an extended User table (inline formset)

Tags: python, django

I extended the Django user in order to have additional fields. I named this entity Persons.

I am using the ModelForm in order to generate my fields. I am making a basic form insertion. When I generate the form, since I am expanding the User model and there exists a one-to-one relationship, the username name shows up as a select box, so users can select from already existing users. However, what I want to do is when a user fills in the form, for a username to be created.

Do I need to create two separate forms with the same submit, or its possible to use an inline formset? What would be the best way to solve this? I am declaring my form like this:

```
def trainer_signup(request):
    TrainerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Trainer)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = TrainerFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # do something.
    else:
        formset = TrainerFormSet()
    return render_to_response("forms.html", {
        "formset": formset,
    })
```

Comment: What django version is this?

Comment: Is the user field on the form always going to the request.user? If so can you ```meta: exclude ('username')``` from screen and then just populate the formset.username = request.user.username in the POST block?